# RabbitMQ (C#): After Ack is sent I want to move item back to queue instead of removing from queue

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, queue

In my program example I have 100 tasks and 5 computers to work on them. My question is about how I can initiate my queue once with these tasks and then keep them permanent (as in a computer finishes a task and instead of a normal acknowledgment after the task is complete where it gets removed, it gets moved back to the queue instead). I want to keep these 100 tasks in my example in a never ending queue that keeps getting worked on by whatever computer is available. I have a prefetch count of 1 meaning a computer can only work on one task at a time.

My current pseudo code is below attempting to do what I'm trying to do but in the end, tasks get removed from the queue and don't seem to be getting added back into the queue all of the time. I started this test last night with the 100 tasks in the queue but by the morning I only had 56 tasks in the queue.

```
public static async Task Dequeue(CancellationToken token)
{
    try
    {
        using var channel = await GetQueue().ConfigureAwait(false);

        if (channel != null)
        {
            var consumer = new AsyncEventingBasicConsumer(channel);
            consumer.Received += async (ch, ea) =>
            {
                var body = ea.Body.ToArray();
                var task = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                var properties = ea.BasicProperties;

                // do long running task here
                await Task.Delay(600000).ConfigureAwait(false);

                // when finished with work then send ack
                channel.BasicAck(ea.DeliveryTag, false);

                // now add to end of queue when work is complete
                channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "",
                                     routingKey: "task_queue",
                                     basicProperties: properties,
                                     body: body);

                await Task.Yield();
            };

            // this consumer tag identifies the subscription
            // when it has to be cancelled
            string consumerTag = channel.BasicConsume("task_queue", false, consumer);
            channel.WaitForConfirmsOrDie(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10000));
            
            while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                // just wait until cancellation is requested
                await Task.Delay(1000, token).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}

public static async Task<IModel?> GetQueue(bool isPublisherMode = true)
{
    try
    {
        var factory = new ConnectionFactory()
        {
            HostName = "localhost",
            Port = 5672,
            UserName = "guest",
            Password = "*******",
            DispatchConsumersAsync = true,
            ContinuationTimeout = new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0),
            HandshakeContinuationTimeout = new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0),
            RequestedConnectionTimeout = new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0)
        };

        var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
        var channel = connection.CreateModel();

        if (isPublisherMode)
        {
            channel.ConfirmSelect();
        }
        
        var args = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "task_queue",
                             durable: true,
                             exclusive: false,
                             autoDelete: false,
                             arguments: args);

        channel.BasicQos(prefetchSize: 0, prefetchCount: 1, global: false);

        Console.WriteLine("[*] Waiting for tasks.");

        return channel;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the new queue type 'streams' in RabbitMQ 3.9.  Works like Kafka where messages stay in the queue for a user-determined length of time.https://www.rabbitmq.com/streams.html

Comment: @ChadKnutson I did look into the new streams but it didn't seem to work for me because I want to keep the same basic First In First Order so as soon as a task completes, it gets sent to the end of the queue to be worked on again. I didn't see an option to do this with streams. It seems to only allow you to choose a starting point you want to work at for example